# How can get year from dropdown and prepare date then set startdate and end date in bootstrap daterange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a form, in this form I have one `dropdown` to select `year` and `text box` for `datepicker`. I am using `bootstrap datepicker`.

What I need is, If I select a year from `dropdown`. I need to set `startDate` and `endDate` in datepicker. `startDate` + 3 is `endDate`.

Eg: If I select 2019 from dropdown. Datepicker calendar need to start with jan 2019 and end with dec 2022.

**Html**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('summerSeasonYear') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                                    <label>@lang('openingClosingSeason.summerSeasonChooseSeasonLabel') <span class="required">*</span></label>

        <select class="form-control" name="summerSeasonYear" id="summerSeasonYear">
          <option value="0">@lang('openingClosingSeason.summerSeasonChooseSeasonSelect')</option>
           <option value="2017" @if(old('summerSeasonYear') == '2017') selected="selected" @endif>2017</option>
           <option value="2018" @if(old('summerSeasonYear') == '2018') selected="selected" @endif>2018</option>
           <option value="2019" @if(old('summerSeasonYear') == '2019') selected="selected" @endif>2019</option>
       </select>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('earliest_summer_open') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="earliest_summer_open">@lang('openingClosingSeason.summerSeasonEarliestOpen') <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="earliest_summer_open" name="earliest_summer_open" placeholder="@lang('openingClosingSeason.summerSeasonEarliestOpenPlaceholder')" data-date-format="dd.mm.yy" readonly="true" value="{{old('earliest_summer_open')}}">
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
var start = '';
    var end   = '';

    setSummerYear(null, null);

    $('#summerSeasonYear').on('change', function(){
        var summerSeasonYear = $("#summerSeasonYear").val();
        $( "#summerSeasonYear" ).attr( "data-summerYear", summerSeasonYear );
        start = new Date();
        end   = new Date(new Date().setYear(start.getFullYear()+1));
        setSummerYear(start, end)
    });


    function setSummerYear(start, end)
    {
        $('#earliest_summer_open').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate : start,
            endDate   : end
        });
    }
```

Comment: `@if(old('summerSeasonYear') == '2017')`this syntax doesn't look like it's vanilla JavaScript and/or jQuery. Please add the tag of the framework you're using to the question

Comment: Use method in docs ... `setDates`. Beyond that you told us what you are wanting to do but not what's wrong with code shown

Comment: @chade_ That is laravel blade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the dateFormat of the jQuery UI (bootstrap uses jQuery!) datepicker to the format you use first upon initialization. I think you did so already on the data-data-format attribute, so that is ok...
Do not initialize the datepicker on demand but do so on document.ready.

Then whenever necessary, set the date of the picker by putting the date into the input, using `.val(date.getDate() + (start.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + start.getFullYear());`.
That is all there is to it; datepicker will handle the change itself when the user decides to click in the input.

Comment: I have tried but not working  'var year = '';
        $('#summerSeasonYear').on('change', function(){
            var summerSeasonYear = $("#summerSeasonYear").val();
            $( '#summerSeasonYear' ).attr( "data-summerYear", summerSeasonYear );
            year = $( '#summerSeasonYear' ).val();
            var start = new Date("January 01, "+year+" 00:00:00");
            var end = new Date(new Date().setYear(start.getFullYear()+1));
            $('#earliest_summer_open').val("01"+"."+"01"+"." +year.toString().substr(2,2));
            console.log(start);
        });'